# Simon in Javascript

Tags: javascript, game, html5, event-handling, simon-says

This is a game of Simon using plain Javascript.  I would welcome any comments, suggestions,
insights or ideas for improvement.  One choice that I made was to have the player's turn 
compare values against a game array ( `simonSays` ) by using the `increment` variable.
If there is a better way to do this I would be very interested.  This program also makes extensive use of the 
`setTimeout` function, if there are other ways to achieve this effect I would also be 
very interested.

Also when I was refactoring and trying to cut unnecessary code I was unable to re-use the call
to the `mute(color)` function from the `playSound(soundValue, i)` and was forced to
use a separate function, `changeColorOff(i)` in this one place.  I left the commented code
in to show what I tried. I am not clear why this was necessary.  Any insights would be appreciated.

The working game is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cgrams/full/VbGXWE/).

```js
var $game = document.getElementById('game'); 
var $sound = document.getElementById('sound');
var $display = document.getElementById('display');
var $displayText = document.getElementById('displayText');
var youWin = null, winnerText = null;

var $yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
var $red = document.getElementById("red");
var $green = document.getElementById("green");
var $blue = document.getElementById("blue");

var $gameOnBtn = document.getElementById('gameOnBtn');
var $startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
var $strictModeBtn = document.getElementById('strictModeBtn');

var powerSound = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=19&type=mp3";
var redSound = " https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3";
var blueSound = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3";
var greenSound = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3";
var yellowSound = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3";
var wrongAnsSound = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1501&type=mp3";
var clickSound = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1705&type=mp3";
var victorySound = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1947&type=mp3";

var powerOn = false;
var gameInPlay = false;
var strictMode = false;
var victory = false;

var buttonTimeInterval = 1000;

var simonSays = [];
var currentValue = null;
var increment = 0;

var soundOptions = {
  0: yellowSound,
  1: redSound,
  2: greenSound,
  3: blueSound 
};

var colorOptions = {
  0: $yellow,
  1: $red,
  2: $green,
  3: $blue
};
function flash(color){
  color.style.opacity = 1;
}

function mute(color){
  color.style.opacity = 0.6;
}

function flashBoard(i, l){
  if (i == l) return;

  setTimeout("flash($yellow)", 500);
  setTimeout("flash($red)", 500);
  setTimeout("flash($green)", 500);
  setTimeout("flash($blue)", 500);

  setTimeout("mute($yellow)", 750);
  setTimeout("mute($red)", 750);
  setTimeout("mute($green)", 750);
  setTimeout("mute($blue)", 750);

  i += 1;
  setTimeout("flashBoard(" + i + "," + l + ")", 500);
 } 

function gameReset(){
  flashBoard(0, 3);
  justSound(powerSound);
  $displayText.textContent = '-- --';
}

function powerOnGame(){
  if (!powerOn){
    $gameOnBtn.style.fill = "rgb(250, 0, 20)"; 
    powerOn = true;
    gameReset();
  } else {
    gameOff();
  }
}

function startGame(){
  if (!powerOn){
    return;
  }
  justSound(clickSound);
  if (!gameInPlay){
    $startBtn.style.fill = "rgb(20, 200, 50)"; 
  } else {
    $startBtn.style.fill = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
    setTimeout(function(){ return $startBtn.style.fill = "rgb(20, 200, 50)";}, 200); 
  }
  resetDisplay(); 
  buttonTimeInterval = 1100;
  simonSays = [];
  playGame();
}

function useStrictMode(){
  if (!powerOn){
    return;
  }
  justSound(clickSound);  
  if (!strictMode){
    $strictModeBtn.style.fill = "rgb(250, 250, 250)"; 
    strictMode = true;
  } else {
    $strictModeBtn.style.fill = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; 
    strictMode = false;
  }
}

//general button handler that take values from color buttons
function colorPress(colorNum){
  if (!powerOn){
    return;
  }
  var colorNo = colorNum; //not sure why this was needed but it was...
  if (currentValue !== colorNum){
    setTimeout(function(){fail()}, 500);
  } else {
    increment += 1;
    currentValue = simonSays[increment];
  }
  flash(colorOptions[colorNum]);
  setTimeout(function(colorNo){
    justSound(soundOptions[colorNum]);
    mute(colorOptions[colorNum]);
  }, 100);
  if (increment === simonSays.length){
    setTimeout(function(){playGame()}, 1000);
  }
}

function pressYellow(){
  colorPress(0);
}

function pressRed(){
  colorPress(1);
}

function pressGreen(){
  colorPress(2);
}

function pressBlue(){
  colorPress(3);
}

function justSound(soundValue){
  $sound.src = soundValue;
  $sound.load();
  $sound.play();
}

//this is the computer's sound function, incorporates the general sound function and an end to the color flash
//not sure why muteColor does not work... 
function playSound(soundValue, i){
  justSound(soundValue);
//  var muteColor = colorOptions[simonSays[i]];
//  setTimeout('mute(' + muteColor + ')', buttonTimeInterval - 300);
  setTimeout('changeColorOff('+ i + ')', buttonTimeInterval - 200);
}

function changeColorOff(i){
  colorOptions[simonSays[i]].style.opacity = 0.6;
}

function displayProgress(arrLen){
  $displayText.setAttribute('font-size', '50');
  $displayText.textContent = arrLen;

  if (arrLen < 10){
    $displayText.setAttribute('x', '227');
  } else {
    $displayText.setAttribute('x', '213');
  }
}

//iterates through the computer's moves
function startPlaying(i, l){
  if (i == l) return;
  increment = 0;
  currentValue = simonSays[0];
  var callSound = soundOptions[simonSays[i]];
  playSound(callSound, i);
  var flashColor = colorOptions[simonSays[i]];
  flash(flashColor);
  i += 1;
  setTimeout("startPlaying("+ i + ", " + l + ")", buttonTimeInterval);
};

function playGame(){
  gameInPlay = true;
  victory = false;
  if (simonSays.length === 20){
    return gameVictory();
  }
  var simonMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  simonSays.push(simonMove);
  startPlaying(0, simonSays.length);
  var simonProgress = simonSays.length;
  if ((simonProgress === 5) || (simonProgress === 9) ){
    buttonTimeInterval -= 250;
  }
  if (simonProgress === 15){
    buttonTimeInterval -= 100;
  }
  displayProgress(simonProgress);
}

function fail(){
  justSound(wrongAnsSound);
  $display.setAttribute("fill", "rgb(200, 0, 0)");
  setTimeout(function(){$display.setAttribute("fill", "rgb(70, 70, 70)");
  }, 1500);
  if (strictMode){
    simonSays = [];
    setTimeout(function(){playGame()}, 2000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){startPlaying(0, simonSays.length)}, 2000);
  }
}

function gameVictory(){
  flashBoard(0, 3);
  justSound(victorySound);
  victory = true;
  $display.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(5, 17, 142)');
  $displayText.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(250, 250, 250)');
  $displayText.textContent = "Win!";
  $displayText.setAttribute('font-size', '20');
  winnerText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'text');
  winnerText.setAttribute('x', '220');
  winnerText.setAttribute('y', '290');
  winnerText.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(250, 250, 250)');
  winnerText.setAttribute('font-size', '20');
  youWin = document.createTextNode("You");
  winnerText.appendChild(youWin);
  $game.appendChild(winnerText);
}

function resetDisplay(){
  $display.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(70, 70, 70)');
  $displayText.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
  if (victory){
    winnerText.parentNode.removeChild(winnerText);
  }
  gameInPlay = true;
}

function gameOff(){
  justSound(clickSound);
  resetDisplay();
  $displayText.textContent = "Off";
  $displayText.setAttribute('font-size', '20');
  $gameOnBtn.style.fill = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; 
  $strictModeBtn.style.fill = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; 
  $startBtn.style.fill = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; 
  simonSays = [];
  victory = false;
  gameInPlay = false;
  strictMode = false;
  powerOn = false;
}

window.onload = gameOff();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(145, 163, 193);
}


#gameShell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

#yellow {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#red {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#green {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#blue {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Draft 1 Simon Shell</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
</head>


<body>
<audio id="sound"></audio>
<div id="gameShell" >
<div id="inner">
<svg id="game" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">

  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="270" fill="black" />

  <path id="yellow" d="M300 50 A250 250, 0, 0,1, 550 300
           L 300 300 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="9" fill="yellow"
           onClick="pressYellow()" />
  <path id="red" d="M550 300 A250 250, 0, 0,1, 300 550
           L 300 300 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="9" fill="red"
           onClick="pressRed()" />
  <path id="green" d="M300 550 A250 250, 0, 0,1, 50 300
           L 300 300 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="9" fill="green"
           onClick="pressGreen()" />
  <path id="blue" d="M50 300 A250 250, 0, 0,1, 300 50
           L 300 300 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="9" fill="blue"
           onClick="pressBlue()" />

  <circle id="innerBackground" cx="300" cy="300" r="120" fill="rgb(244, 244, 20)" stroke="black" stroke-width-"15" />
  <text x="255" y="235" font-family="arial" font-size="30" font-weight="bold" >Simon</text>
  <text x="290" y="320" font-family="arial" font-size="20"  >Start</text>
  <text x="350" y="320" font-family="arial" font-size="20"  >Strict</text>
  <text x="270" y="395" font-family="arial" font-size="20"  >On/Off</text>

  <circle id="startBtn" cx="315" cy="285" r="10" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
    onClick="startGame()" />
  <circle id="strictModeBtn" cx="375" cy="285" r="10" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
    onClick="useStrictMode()" />
  <circle id="gameOnBtn" cx="300" cy="360" r="10" fill="black"
   stroke-width="5"stroke="black" onClick="powerOnGame()" />

  <rect id="display" x="205" y="260" rx="10" ry="20" width="70" height="70" fill="rgb(70, 70, 70)" stroke="black" />
  <text id="displayText" x='225' y='310' font-size='20' >Off</text>

</svg>
</div>
</div>

<h1>Simon</h1>
<script src="logic.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use a snippet, this would actually be playable right here on CR!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I assumed that the editors had inset the snippets and I wasn't aware of how to use [that feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)   myself.  I will definitely use it in the future, much easier than an external link...thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### General Feedback

The code appears to work acceptable. The HTML does have javascript calls inline (e.g. `onclick="pressYellow()"`). It would be better to separate the event handling logic out into the Javascript.

I see it caches DOM element references instead of querying for DOM elements each time they are needed. This is great.

### Suggestions

There are a couple different usages of `setTimeout()` used. The first is okay:

> ```
> setTimeout(function(){playGame()}, 1000);
> ```

But the extra anonymous/lambda/closure function is unnecessary. A reference to the function can be passed instead:

```
setTimeout(playGame, 1000);
```

Then there are places where a string literal is passed - e.g.

> ```
> setTimeout("flash($yellow)", 500);
> ```

but it is recommended not to use that format - see the MDN documentation for [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

> #### code
>
> An alternative syntax that allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed when the timer expires. This syntax is **not recommended** for the same reasons that make using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) a security risk.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters)</sup>

To specify parameters to be passed to the function when it is called, use a [partially-applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions):

```
setTimeout(flash.bind(null, $yellow));
```

That should also allow you to use the `mute` function in `playSound()` as you originally wanted.

```
setTimeout(mute.bind(null, muteColor), buttonTimeInterval - 300);
```

---

Instead of four separate rulesets in the CSS for the opacity:

> ```
> #yellow {
>   opacity: 0.5;
> }
> #red {
>   opacity: 0.5;
> }
> #green {
>   opacity: 0.5;
> }
> #blue {
>   opacity: 0.5;
> }
> ```

The CSS selectors can be combined into a single ruleset:

```
#yellow,
#red , 
#green, 
#blue {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters</sub>